# Paypal Subscription revise with prorata

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I would like to make a system where my clients could upgrade their subscription plans.
Let's say I have a user who has à monthly subscription, and he wants to update it to the annual subscription.
I need it to take place immediately because he has access to more content when he has the annual subscription, but there also needs to be a pro rata on the payment. For example for the monthly subscription he paid €30, but he immediately upgraded to the annual subscription, the annual subscription is €100, so he is going to pay 100 - 30 = €70 for the upgrade. But I need it to be only on the first billing cycle, the following cycle he has to pay €100.

I tried doing this with the subscription/revise endpoint like this:

```
    let paypalSubscription = await fetch(`${process.env.PAYPAL_API_URL}/v1/billing/subscriptions/${subscription.paypal.subscriptionId}/revise`, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            plan_id: planIds[data.planType],
            plan: {
                billing_cycles: [{
                    sequence: 1,
                    pricing_scheme: {
                        fixed_price: {
                            currency_code: "EUR",
                            value: "70"
                        }
                    }
                }]
            }
        })
    });
```

It returns me a link for the customer to go and approve the new subscription, which looks like this:
https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/billing/subscriptions/update?ba_token=TOKEN

**First problem**: when I go on this page it seems to work, and when I finalize the payment I get this error:

[image]

Which translates to: "The system isn't working right now. Please try again later"

When I go to the sandbox account and check my subscriptions, the plan update has been done, but the €70 payment hasn't.

**Second problem**: when I check the updated subscription, it says that it will be €70 for each billing cycle, but I want it to be only for the first one.

Does anyone know how to make this work ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need two billing cycles, the first one a tenure_type:trial with total_cycles:1. Something like..

```
  "billing_cycles": [
    {
      "frequency": {
        "interval_unit": "YEAR",
        "interval_count": 1
      },
      "tenure_type": "TRIAL",
      "sequence": 1,
      "total_cycles": 1,
      "pricing_scheme": {
        "fixed_price": {
          "value": "70",
          "currency_code": "EUR"
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "frequency": {
        "interval_unit": "YEAR",
        "interval_count": 1
      },
      "tenure_type": "REGULAR",
      "sequence": 2,
      "total_cycles": 0,
      "pricing_scheme": {
        "fixed_price": {
          "value": "100",
          "currency_code": "EUR"
        }
      }
    }
  ],
```

Comment: Tried it, but I get the error: 'The provided billing cycle sequence is not available.' for sequence: 2. I don't understand why because in the docs it's written that the sequence can go from 1 to 99

Comment: Make a new plan_id with two cycles.

Comment: Hum I did that (by adding a trial cycle) but when I go to the url to subscribe to the new subscription, it doesn't make me pay 70€ but 100€, like it ignores the trial cycle

Comment: What is the plan id you created? Do a GET request on it and include the response in your question.

Comment: But well, I suppose trial cycles may not work when revising a subscription. You'd have to have the payer approve a newly-created one and cancel the previous one.

Comment: Tbh, the more I look into it, the more I think it ain't possible. I guess I'll just have the user cancel it's current subscription and subscribe to a new one...
Anyway thank you for your time